# Display data without refreshing page in React

Tags: reactjs, node.js, websocket, refresh, real-time

I have data tables that are updated every few seconds in my db.
I want to display them in react in real time -
when there is an update in the db,
the information displayed in react will be
updated automatically without refreshing the page.
for example-

```
 useEffect(() => {
         const apiUrl = 'http://localhost:3001/main-table/receptionQueue';
         axios.get(apiUrl)
             .then(response => {
                 setQueue(response.data);
             })
             .catch(error => {
                 console.error('Error fetching reception queue data:', error);
             });
      }, []);
```

When I run the above code - it's one get request.
And when I remove the square brackets it's a lot of get requests without a break-
Which causes slowness and high resource consumption.
Does anyone know how to write it in such a way that only when there is an update in the database,
a get request will be performed on the client side?

I use:
database - MongoDb , backend - Node.js , frontend - React

Any solution would really help me!
Thank you:)

I tried to make a webSocket but it got a bit complicated....

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @m_c Which database/backend framework are you using? there are a lot of approaches, you can make a trigger to update a log table then poll that table for changes; or you can use sse/ websocket of course. There is no "right" answer, it depends on your need, so please provide more information.

Comment: I use:
database - MongoDb , backend - Node.js ,  frontend - React

Answer (score 0):

1.Use useState()

2. When do you want to get new data? every few seconds? if so, put it all in a timer

Here is an example:

```
  const [data, setData] = useState();
  useEffect(() => {
    const apiUrl = "http://localhost:3001/main-table/receptionQueue";
    const interval = setInterval(function () {
      axios
        .get(apiUrl)
        .then((response) => {
          setData(response.data);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.error("Error fetching reception queue data:", error);
        });
    }, 5000);
    return () => {
      clearInterval(interval);
    };
  }, []);
```

Comment: First of all, thanks for the answer!
If it is data that is updated every few seconds. (it is not known exactly how many seconds)
Is it possible to set a TimeOut of 1 second? Wouldn't something like that burden the system?
It's an app that should be on all day...

Comment: Usually requesting a Get query is not such a big deal. but I don't know the details of your app so look into it. Also, You can change the interval time based on whether the user is focused on the web page or not to optimize your request.